# how to hosting multiple Nodejs applications with nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx

I understand that multiple node.js can be run on one server using Nginx. I've got Nginx setup and running on a Ubuntu server. I have two node js applications :

```
    127.0.0.1:3001 and 
    127.0.0.1:3002
```

. I want to access the different application with different url. For example, if I want access

```
    127.0.0.1:3001
```

, I would use url:

```
 http://121.42.20.100/
```

. And if want access the application of

```
    127.0.0.1:3002
```

, I would use url:

```
 http://121.42.20.100/admin
```

the default file on the folder sites-available follows :

```
    server {
            #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
            #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

            root /usr/share/nginx/www;
            index index.html index.htm;

            # Make site accessible from `    http://localhost/`
            server_name 0.0.0.0;

            location / {

                   proxy_pass `    http://127.0.0.1:3001`;

            }

            location /admin/ {
                    proxy_pass `    http://127.0.0.1:3002`;
            }
    }
```

When I access url like

```
http://121.42.29.100/
```

, it works that get response from

```
 
    127.0.0.1:3001
```

. However, when I access url like

```
http://121.42.29.100/admin
```

, it does not work that it shows error of "Cannot GET /admin/". How can I configure the nginx to get it work?

Comment: The error "Cannot GET /admin/" is a node.js process error, right?

Comment: no, it shows on the webpage, try this url: http://121.42.29.243/psadmin/

Comment: Yes, I mean: this is NOT an nginx error, but an application error. In this case you can try with a rewrite inside the `location /admin/` like: `rewrite ^/admin/(.*)$ /$1 break;`